# make linux shell send domain instead of ip when use socks5 proxy

Tags: shell, proxy, dns, tsocks

I'm trying to write a socks5 proxy.

When I setup the proxy by `export ALL_PROXY=socks5://domain:port`, 
and then execute commond `curl www.google.com`, my proxy server always recieves a 'IP' instead of domain for google in the hand shake data. This intends that the local system did DNS search before send the IP to a socks5 proxy server.

I want to konw how can I make a linux shell send domain instead of IP when use socks5 proxy just like `socks_remote_dns` setted firefox browser.

Comment: You may need `curl` argument `--preproxy`.